# Ethereum pets in a room game

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, random

There are 64 rooms and `N` players. Each player has a random number of coins up to one million.

- Each player takes one or several pets and gives them their coins.
- The pets are then taken one by one and randomly placed in one of the 64 rooms
- Finally, one of the pets' coins is randomly selected in each room. The owner of the coin wins a price.

What strategy will earn more prices, give all the coins to one pet or share them equally between several pets? Or will the chances be the same?

*Assume that random is equal distribution.*

I came to this problem while learning about Etherume 2.0 sharding mechanism. My gut tells me that having more pets is more beneficial, but I can't prove it mathematically. Please tell me what the correct answer is.

Comment: The rules are pretty vague.  Might my pets happen to be assigned to the same room or does "random" exclude that?  Are we to assume that the others follow the same strategy we do or is the question more a matter of finding a Nash Equilibrium (or something along those lines)?  What is my utility function?  Am I just trying to maximize the number of my prizes or am I competing with the other players?  Do I know how many coins the other players have?

Comment: Some clarifying questions: 1. So each room can have multiple pets? 2. What is the selection process? You select one random coin from one random pet in each room (so that there are 64 prizes)? Or do you only do this for one randomly selected room?

Comment: It seems odd that a player can have a million coins.  That suggests that a player can stuff all the rooms filled with hundreds of their pets.  Is that really what is intended?

Comment: @lulu yes, it is possible that all your pets end up in one room. We don't know about the strategy of each player. Your goal is to win as many prizes as possible. You do know how many coins other players have. A player can theoretically staff all the rooms with hundreds of pets if he has enough coins.

Comment: @angryavian one coin in each room, so there are 64 prizes.

Comment: If everybody is trying to maximize their own score, cooperative strategies are possible.  That is, player $A$ shouldn't care if player $B's$ expected score goes up, so long as theirs does as well.  That may help.

Comment: Just to say:  it's clear, I think, that it's not always better to spread your coins around.  If, say, my opponent has a million coins and I have $30,000$...then my opponent can spread uniformly and will probably get more than $15,000$ per room.  If I spread too thin, I'll get nothing.  Better to put all my coins into one room (or something like that) to at least have a shot.

Comment: Or maybe I have that wrong. If I divide uniformly, I'll have around $469$ per room and, while it's unlikely that I'll win any particular room, I get an expected  value of $1.86407767$ prizes which is certainly better than I get out of concentration. So if my goal is optimizing expectation, it seems it is better to spread out, counter to my intuition.

Comment: @lulu I share your intuition, but I like to see mathematical proof.

Comment: I would look at cooperative strategies.  See if it makes sense to make a deal to concentrate.  That way both players "guarantee" a bunch of wins and they have a decent shot of winning even when some of the rooms double up.  I suggest studying that with a small set of rooms...the phenomenon should be general.